# constant expression required when trying to create a switch case block

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio-flamingo

`an error keeps saying "constant expression required" preventing me from running the app on a device to further develop the app.

am trying to create a sort of google pay.. so i need the selected amounts. but am getting an error saying "constant expression required".. the variable is declared private and not final so i dont know why am getting this error. the value is not even highlighted showing that it is being used. how can i solve this error. i tried innitialising the variable to zero but it still does not help..
`

```
package com.example.greenearth;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Donations extends Fragment {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton minimum;
    RadioButton average;
    RadioButton maximum;
    private int google_amount=0;

    RelativeLayout rl;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_donations, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        radioGroup=view.findViewById(R.id.select);
        minimum=view.findViewById(R.id.fifty);
        average=view.findViewById(R.id.five_hundred);
        maximum=view.findViewById(R.id.ten_thousand);
        rl=view.findViewById(R.id.donater);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId){
                    case R.id.fifty:
                        google_amount=50;
                        break;

                    case R.id.five_hundred:
                        google_amount=500;
                        break;

                    case R.id.ten_thousand:
                        google_amount=10000;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (google_amount>0) {
                    //googlepay
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please choose an amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: which line gives you this error?

Comment: your problem seems to be that in lines like this: case R.id.fifty: -> the R.id.fifty is not a compile time constant

Comment: @Stultuske all the id's i reference in each case give the error

Comment: yes, meaning that my previous comment applies to all of them.

Answer (score 36):

Starting with Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.0, by default, your resources (e.g. `R.id. ...`) are no longer declared `final` (i.e. constant expressions) for optimized build speed, which is a prerequisite to be used in switch statements:
https://developer.android.com/build/optimize-your-build#use-non-constant-r-classes

If you want to keep the old behavior, you can add this line in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

If you want to fix it by converting it to if/else statements, Android Studio will help you with

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> or

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

on the `switch` keyword.

Answer (score 13):

Put this line

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

In this file and sync

```
gradle.properties
```

That's works for me

Answer (score 3):

Replace your switch statement with if condition like below

```
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if (checkedId == R.id.fifty) {
                google_amount = 50;
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.five_hundred) {
                google_amount = 500;
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.ten_thousand) {
                google_amount = 10000;
            }
        }
    });
```

If you encounter the "constant expression required" error, ensure that the expression used in the switch statement is indeed a constant expression. If you need to evaluate a non-constant expression, you might consider using if-else statements instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

This works for me

file gradle.properties