R.id.* is not recognized any more after upgrade to Gradle 8.3.2 and gradle-8.4-bin.zip
After upgrading to gradle 8.3.2 and  gradle-8.4-bin.zip, I am getting this error in Android Studio:
Error: constant expression required
then, fouind this link:  constant expression required when trying to create a switch case block and apply this in the gradle.properties file and the error is gone:
android.nonFinalResIds=false
but for those layout file where material UI is used:
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/myId" .../>

the id within TextInputLayout is not recognized any more, e.g:
binding.myId.findViewById(R.id.text_input_end_icon)

I have to append the full path to make it recognized again:
binding.myId.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.text_input_end_icon)

I tried to do import like this after my app's own R import:
import com.google.android.material.R.id.*;

but it shows it's greyed which means not in use at all. I don't want to add this prefix everywhere in the code base. Any hints will be highly appreciated!
Thanks
Shawn

Instead of using workarounds like nonFinalResIds I would update your code to work without final IDs like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76445467/150978 And regarding the R class I would assume you are using the wrong R class. Libraries can have their own R class, but usually you use the R class of your app as this is where your Ids are saved to. So the correct glass should be <your_app_packagename>.R.

I already changed switch to if/else, the problem is that for those constants defined in com.google.android.material.R.id, the import doesn't work, such that I have to put full path to the id such like: com.google.android.material.R.id.text_input_end_icon

Normally you simply define your own IDs instead of refusing them from an existing R class.
